# Rendering pages

Tags: loop

I'm making a custom wordpress theme for the first time and I am having an issue. I have a static `index.php` file and I created `page.php` file which looks like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile; else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

From the Admin Panel I created a gallery. However when I click on an image it redirects me to `?attachment_id=10` and on this page the `index.php` file gets rendered.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It's gallery. Did you create gallery inside page or post. ?

Comment: When you are editing/inserting the gallery in your page, [look for the "Link To" setting](http://i.imgur.com/seb5T1X.png), and change "Attachment Page" to "Media File" - don't forget to update & save the page too.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress template hierarchy is your friend.
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

This provides a very detailed flow for how WP determines which template to load.

If you are ever uncertain about which template is loading, this little function is handy.  Paste in your theme's functions.php and it will display the template used at the bottom of the page.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpse_show_template');

function wpse_show_template() {
  global $template;
  print_r($template);
}
```

Comment: I usually like to add mine to the `wp_head` hook. ;-)